# Java ActionCommand

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe

Is there a method to get the button associated with a particular command string?
For instance if I define a button with:

```
button.setActionCommand("unique_toggle");
```

Having that string "unique_toggle", is it possible to retrieve that button from another class? I am beginner at Java, excuse if this question may seem obvious to you.

Comment: Have the 'other class' be the action listener. Use [`EventObject.getSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource--) in the action performed method. See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), as this sounds much like one.

Comment: Will definitely try that, thanks

Comment: Will EventObject.getSource() solve my problem? Since I never press that button. I only have the string to which that buttons setActionCommand is referring to.

Comment: Let's come back the 'XY problem' and .. **Why** do you think one class needs to know the text of a button that has not been pressed in another class? It ..screams of a broken design to me.

Comment: Note also *"I am beginner at Java"* GUIs are an advance topic. By the time you approach making a GUI, all this 'basic OO' / 'variable scope' / 'design' stuff should be clear. Perhaps you should step back from making GUIs for the moment and learn those basics in command line apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access to your button and its associated button's command. If you need to a button's command, that possibly means that you should consider redesining your programm because this approach is **not advisable** and very dirty way to do what you want to achieve.

When it comes to answer to your question,

Lets say `Foo1` is your `GUI` class.

```
class Foo1{

JButton button;

public Foo1(Foo2 otherClass)
{
button = new JButton();
otherClass.setButtonAddress(button);
}
..... other methods
}
```

`Foo2` is the class, in where you want to access button's command text.

```
class Foo2{
JButton buttonFromOtherClass;

//This is the method, in where you need command string of the button

private void getCommandsString()
{
Foo1 foo1 = new Foo1(this);

//After the initialization of Foo1, you can get every information of the button
  String actionCommand = buttonFromOtherClass.getActionCommand();
}


public void setButtonAddress(JButton button)
{
buttonFromOtherClass = button;
}

}
```